Name of a children's action mystery movie
When I was a kid I saw this movie in which some boy was chased around by some bad guys. The boy played some video game and I think the bad guys were part of it (the game) in some way.
During the chase he met once or twice this kind elderly couple who helped him get away from the bad guys. I don't remember all the details, but I think he tried to get some help from some computer wizz, however in a later scene the CRT screen of said character had a bullet hole in it and the character himself was nowhere to be found (presumably dead).
Later on I think he was helped by main character from the game he played (some kind of soldier) who came to life. In another scene the bad guys had the kid and the character from the game cornered. I think the kid had a chance to shoot one of the bad guys, but was too afraid to do so and the bad guys shoot the game character to death instead (or the character jumped to save the kid from being shot to death). I think this scene took place on a street during night. In this scene (or right before), the game character was trying to convince the boy to kill the bad guys arguing that he (the game character) did that for the boy all the time in the game. I'm not sure if normal people could see the game character or it was just the kid (and maybe the bad guys too).
The climax of the movie took place inside an airport. The kid ran yet again into the elderly couple and to convince them that what he says is true (about being chased by the bad guys), he tells them that he found out, that the bad guys take orders from a person who has just had two finger in the right (or was it left) hand. At this point the granny took off her glove and revealed that she was actually the leader of the bad guys all this time (what a twist). At the last moment boy's father showed up and saved the day. I don't remember what he did, but a plane with the elderly couple on board exploded and the movie ended.
Can anyone tell me the name of the movie I described above?
For a moment I though that this was a Polish movie called Łowca - Ostatnie starcie, but I managed to find a copy of said movie and although the plot is quite similar, it's still a different movie. The boy did play a video game, but the character from the game didn't came to life. He met an elderly couple, but they were not kind and just had a minor role (they weren't missing any fingers either). He met a computer wizz, but the guy didn't die or disappear. The climax of the movie also took place inside an airport and involved the boy's father but the events were different. My gut is telling me that Łowca - Ostatnie starcie actually saw release outside of Poland, but I can't find any proof of that (not even a title in English) anywhere (since it was a medicore children's movie from 1993 it's not all that surprising).

@Walt Thank you. This indeed appear to be the movie. Incidentally the other movie that I mentioned in my question appears to have been heavily "inspired" by Cloak & Dagger (although it was made to be more family friendly).

It has been answered in the comments but I will add the answer. The movie is Cloak and Dagger http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloak_%26_Dagger_(1984_film)

If it's a duplicate (and the asker approved this), it doesn't need to be answered but rather to be closed, I think. The question's already been asked and answered before.

Gotcha, thanks for the clarification.
